# Tomcat 7 as windows service not accessible from other systems

Tags: windows, tomcat, windows-7, tomcat7

I have downloaded Tomcat 7 zip for 32 bit windows 7 machine.  I have unzipped the package and created the windows service using ..\bin\service.bat. But when i start the service from windows services.msc, i could NOT access by web application from other systems. It can be accessed from localhost.

But when i start the tomcat from command line using ..\bin\startup.bat i CAN access my web application from other systems.

I have added address="0.0.0.0" in ..\conf\server.xml of tomcat. But still the problem exists. Tried with adding exception in firewall too. But no luck.

OS: Windows 7 Professional

Any ideas??

```
Solution:

Add the ..\bin\tomcat7.exe to the Windows exception list. Everything works fine.
1. To to Windows Start --> Control Panel
2. Open windows firewall
3. Click on "Allow a program or feature through windows firewall" in the left menu
4. Add tomcat7.exe to the exception list and click ok.
5. Restart tomcat and now you can access tomcat from other machines
```

Comment: we also had this trouble.  It was the firewall.

Comment: Stop the Windows Firewall service and see if issue still persist. Please note that this question is not code related and so should have been asked in either Server Fault or Super User

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Solution:

Add the ..\bin\tomcat7.exe to the Windows exception list. Everything works fine.
1. Go to Windows Start --> Control Panel
2. Open windows firewall
3. Click on "Allow a program or feature through windows firewall" in the left menu
4. Add tomcat7.exe to the exception list and click ok.
5. Restart tomcat and now you can access tomcat from other machines
```

Comment: Ok this solved my problem but why it works when it is not installed as a service?

Comment: This means you need to set inbound to allow TCP and UDP to allow from firewall of the system where tomcat server is installed.

Comment: For me this was already there in the list with name "Common Deamon Service Runner" and all I had to do is select also "public" checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

I start Tomcat7 using Eclipse java IDE and I had to disable the Windows 7 firewall rules blocking "program files\java\jre\javaw.exe" for both TCP and UDP.  Then my other PC could access the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to install tomcat as a win service to make it available from outside.

If you have already install tomcat, then you can register it as service using below command.

service.bat install/remove [service_name] [/user username]

Both will solve the issue.